# Is there a practical limit for an apache ignite cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ignite

We are planning to use Apache Ignite for our production system.  Right now we are thinking our combined RAM will be less than a terabyte, but in the near-ish future that number will be increasing.

Does anyone have information in regards to a current production system using ignite?  We are going to be using be using AWS w/s3 to corral the cluster.  Probably servers with ram less than 32G in order to take advantage of `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`.

Some concerns include:

- Number of servers in the cluster.  Is there a practical number that we shouldn't exceed.
- Total size in terms of ram.  Is there a practical number that we shouldn't exceed.
- Performance of backup-key shuffle on node loss/addition
- Stability over time.  Does the cluster performance degrade and will benefit from periodic restarts or is it currently (1.7) stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there is no limit, but bigger clusters can of course require more tuning. I've personally seen cluster of up to 1000 nodes successfully running in production environments. As for the memory, you can use large instances and off-heap memory [1] to store the data.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/off-heap-memory

Comment: Do you know of any advanced tuning guides or books?